# Interrupted time series control group

Tags: time-series, causality, medicine

I'm conducting the analysis on readmission rate for a hospital unit between 2009 and 2012. I have a list of "historical" data where patients did not have the intervention. I then have a different set of patients who did get the intervention.

My question is, is it enough to consider the historical dataset as a comparison group in the analysis? Ideally, I'd want a similar (non-equivalent) comparison group who did not get the intervention and followed after initiation of the intervention, but I don't believe this is available (from speaking with the data managers). Also having multiple baseline groups would increase my confidence in the intervention effecting the change in readmission. If I don't have this data, is it still ok to use the single baseline group?

Comment: Perhaps if you share your data someone might be able to help.

Comment: I'm afraid the data is not accessible at this moment - still going through IRB process to get access to it.